# Подсчет количества постов

Tags: php_pdo, php, mysql

Нужно сосчитать количество постов. Использовал

```
mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) ...
```

Как сделать это в PDO лучшим способом?

Answer (score 1):

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from tables');

if ($row = $STH->fetch()) 
{  
    $STH->rowCount();
}
```

Работает в зависимости от версии MySQL